# Elements of the jQuery scripts work when going back to a page on the browser but not on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2013, owl-carousel, mixitup

I am using bootstrap script, mixitup filtering and owl carousel on a SharePoint page. For example on the owlcarousel the data shows up but the actual carousel function does not work. If i leave the page and then go back -1 everything works. It is the only time it works. When I refresh or reload it goes back to the original state.

On the mixitup filtering a similar issue happens. The data does not load initially like it should. When i leave the page and go back then it loads and functions properly.

Any ideas? Something with caching and loading order of scripts? Why would it work when going back?

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the scripts in this order in the end of your body:
jQuery,
Bootstrap,
owlcarousel
Then your custom Script which initiates any own functions

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I tried re-ordering the scripts but it either broke something else or did not do anything. I think because of all the SharePoint related scripts loading something was happening there. waiting to load my scripts until the page fully loaded fixed the issue.

Comment: When you open the browser console , what errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

After weeks of searching and deciding to post the question I found my answer so I wanted to make sure i shared.

I found a post from Chris Coyier on how to run JavaScript only after the entire page has loaded...  THAT WAS IT! Once i placed my script in this it fixed my issue.

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
       // code here
    });
```